# How to add a jar, source and Javadoc to the local Maven repository?

Tags: maven

I'm wanting to add the latest version of JGoodies Forms (1.5.0) as a dependency, but I can't find anything newer than 1.0.5 in the main repository, so if I understand correctly, the next best thing I can do is add it to my local repository.

When I download it from the website, I get a ZIP file that contains the javadoc files, the source code and the jar (with just class files in it).

What is the procedure for adding this to my local Maven repository in such a way that Eclipse will be able to see the source and Javadoc? (I've only just started using Maven)

Comment: Note that the gourpId has been changed since 1.0.7, from [jgoodies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jgoodies/forms) to [com.jgoodies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jgoodies/forms), the latest version you can download from online repository is 1.2.1.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is the syntax to deploy the binary, the sources and the javadoc with a single command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -DgroupId=com.jgoodies \
    -DartifactId=jgoodies-forms \
    -Dversion=1.6.0 \
    -Dfile=jgoodies-forms-1.6.0.jar \
    -Dsources=jgoodies-forms-1.6.0-sources.jar \
    -Djavadoc=jgoodies-forms-1.6.0-javadoc.jar \
    -Durl=file://path/to/your/local/repository
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: It's especially important to do it THIS way and NOT the other way if you're doing a snapshot rather than a release, since the snapshot ids will be different for the source jar vs the classes jar otherwise, and maven won't know that the sources correspond to the classes

Comment: Updated my answer to point to Emmanuel's as his is the better way of doing this.

Answer (score 51):

**Update**: *Even though this is the accepted answer, please check the answer of Emmanuel Bourg below - his answer is probably what you would like to do, especially if you're having a snapshot version.*

---

You can use the maven deploy plugin for that. It has a goal for deploying a single file to any repository.
For the jar itself:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -DgroupId=com.yourname.jgoodies \
    -DartifactId=jgoodies-forms \
    -Dversion=1.50 \
    -Dfile=/path/to/jgoodies-1.50.jar \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -Durl=file://path/to/your/local/repository
```

For the sources:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -DgroupId=com.yourname.jgoodies \
    -DartifactId=jgoodies-forms \
    -Dversion=1.50 \
    -Dfile=/path/to/jgoodies-sources.jar \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -Durl=file://path/to/your/local/repository \
    -Dclassifier=sources
```

For the javadoc:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -DgroupId=com.yourname.jgoodies \
    -DartifactId=jgoodies-forms \
    -Dversion=1.50 \
    -Dfile=/path/to/jgoodies-javadoc.jar \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -Durl=file://path/to/your/local/repository \
    -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

Note that this will generate a standard POM, so you won't have the dependencies of JGoodies (if any) pulled automatically but have to specify them manually in your project.

Comment: Thanks for going into detail for each specific statement

Comment: You can specify the `-Djavadoc` and `-Dsources` parameters to do the same thing with only one command.

Answer (score 4):

Install the jar you have downloaded using this mini guide :

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

You should install jgoodies-form-1.5.0.jar by typing:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>/jgoodies-form-1.5.0.jar \ 
-DgroupId=jgoodies -DartifactId=forms -Dversion=1.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

don't forget to do the same with jgoodies-commons.

For you to be able to access the source code and the contextual javadoc you can either

- uncompress the jgoodies form zip and make eclipse points to the src folder
- generates a jgoodies-form-1.5.0-src.jar by putting the src directory in it and install it in your local repo the same way you did for the jar