# Adding A Group of Files to a Local Maven Repository

Tags: maven

I have an existing java project.  It is a maven project.  I want to add it to my local maven repository for reuse in other projects.

```
MyUtilityClass.jar
MyUtilityClassSources.jar
MyUtilityClassDocs.jar
```

Dependent on

```
slf4j-1.7.2.jar
junit-4.11.jar
```

This [SO Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/adding-local-jars-in-maven-project) gives instructions for adding a single file to a local maven repository using  mvn install:install-file

This [SO Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386589/how-to-add-a-jar-source-and-javadoc-to-the-local-maven-repository) gives instructions for adding a group of jars - sources, javadoc, etc. using mvn deploy-file.

This [SO Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689136/add-multiple-jars-and-javadoc-to-local-maven-repository) alludes to specifying dependencies via a pom.xml file, but doesn't provide details.

I have two tasks in front of me that I'd like to accomplish:

1. add the project for MyUtilityClass to my local repository, with sources, docs, and dependencies automatically added when I pull them in.
2. I'd like to create a maven task for the MyUtilityClass project that adds the latest and greatest bundle to my local repository.

I am using eclipse as an IDE and maven version 3.0.4.  The POM for this project looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.local.mine</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyUtilityClass</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>MyUtilityClass</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.local.mine</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j</artifactId><!--from local repo -->
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.local.mine</groupId>
        <!--from local repo and shouldn't be automatically added -->
        <!-- to projects that reuse the resulting bundle -->
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to think of each project as their own release cycles.  They should be independant of each other.

As you have discovered, you can

- use install to install the artifact to your local repository
- use install-file to install secondary artifacts to your local repository
- use deploy to so the same steps as install(-file), but to remote repositories

What also does this is the release plugin.  When you perform the pair goals of release:prepare and release:perform, you end up with

- version values update in the pom files
- version control tags created
- the artifact installed & deployed
- any source and/or javadoc artifacts deployed

What you want to use is the [release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use

```
mvn install
```

in the project you would like to reuse. This will install the artifacts of your project into your location repository.