# crystal report jars for maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, crystal-reports, pom.xml

I have built a non-maven project to display crystal reports with all necessary jars imported to the lib folder.

But, when I try to find the dependencies to add the same jars into my pom.xml for a maven project, I was not able to look it up online.

*How can I find the crystal report dependencies for a maven project ? How to determine groupId and artifact for the crystal jar?*

Below is the snapshot of jars I am looking for. Please suggest.

[image]

I tried looking into this [link in the SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1040242) but couldn't find much details.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689136/add-multiple-jars-and-javadoc-to-local-maven-repository

Comment: @craig: Thank you for the share, I was able to deploy jars to m2 directly and reference it in my pom.xml, rather than point to local using system scope.

Comment: I'd love to see this stuff added to Maven--using a package manager would really simplify matters.

Comment: Agree! In the first place, when the jars are available for development, I was wondering why Maven repository didn't have it? Also, a package manager is surely essential. We uploaded them to our local artifactory now, which is much more simpler.

Comment: Useful: http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer

Answer (score 2):

You can specify your local jars as maven dependency using "system" scope

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${lib.path}/some_1.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

define 'lib.path' in properties

Comment: Thank you. I tried to add:<dependency>
            <groupId>com.crystaldecisions</groupId>
            <artifactId>CrystalReportsRuntime</artifactId>
            <version>${com.crystaldecisions.version}</version>
             <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${lib.path}\CrystalReportsRuntime.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency> and      <properties>
   <com.crystaldecisions.version>1.5</com.crystaldecisions.version>
     <lib.path>C:\mavenjars\crjava-runtime_12.2.215\lib</lib.path>
  </properties> but the class does not import the needed classes. It shows an error still.

Comment: what's the error you get? is it correct the artifactId and groupId?

Comment: It is exactly what I am looking for. I am not able to figure the dependencies for crystal reports maven.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to change the scope. How would this affect when the pom is checked into SVN ? Is it a recommended way to point to local jars using maven ? Please give more insight, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Below are two solutions : One is pointing to local jars with system scope and the other is deploying the jars into m2. I felt the second solution more reliable.

First solution: I followed the link [here](https://gist.github.com/ulinkwo/1553207) ; but couldn't get it entirey working. So changed the scope to system and pointed to the local jars and was able to finally access the classes.
Please see below for the pom.xml

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.crystalReports</groupId>
            <artifactId>CrystalCommon2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-RT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${lib.path}/CrystalCommon2.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        .....
```

Second solution is, from the comment in the question above, I came up with the idea of deploying all the crystal jars, one by one, which I downloaded on my local into my local m2 repository.

```
    mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.crystalruntime.sdk  -DartifactId=JDBInterface  
-Dversion=1.5   -Dfile= point-to-the-jar-location-on your-local\JDBInterface.jar  
-Dpackaging=jar  -Durl=file://point-to-local-m2 repository
```

`groupId, artifactId,version`- can be modified, but it is good to keep consistency and readability, with the names chosen.
Run this command on any/all the jars that you want to install into m2. I then updated the project and did another clean build and was able to successfully run then application.
Also, I did remove the system scope from the pom.xml

```
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${lib.path}/JDBInterface.jar</systemPath>
```

and modified it according to :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.crystalruntime.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>JDBInterface</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

This made more sense to me, to use in the maven project.
This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386589/how-to-add-a-jar-source-and-javadoc-to-the-local-maven-repository) I followed for reference.